# Swift - Placeholder long text - cut the middle

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, placeholder

I have `UITextField` with long placeholder like this:
"QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM", but my textfield is small and when I use function `textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` the `minimumFontSize` that I can set is 9 but still I can't fit the text into the textField. I want to cut the middle of the text and I expect the text to be "QWERTY...CVBNM" how to do that?

Comment: Usually in IB you can set the paragraph style to Truncate Middle.

Comment: My textField is programmaticaly

Comment: I'm on OSX but there's a `TextFieldCell` inside `NSTextField` which has `setUpFieldEditorAttributes` where you can modify the paragraph style.

Comment: UILabel allows truncation in the middle, but I don't see this option for UITextField in IB.

Comment: thats why I asked the question :)

Comment: ok is there a function that I can create which takes first 5 and last 5 letters from the string and in the middle put dots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func cutTheMiddleOfLongString(var string:String) -> String {
    if(countElements(string)>20){
        let begining = string[advance(string.startIndex, 0)..<advance(advance(string.startIndex, 0), 12)]
        let ending = string[advance(string.startIndex, countElements(string)-8)..<advance(advance(string.startIndex, countElements(string)-8), 8)]
        string = begining + "..." + ending
    }
    return string
}
```

This will take first 12 letters and last 8 letters of the string and will put ... between them(begining ending).